# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property - fetch from firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I attempted *ngIf validation data from Firestore. few users have only **head = true** data in firestore. need to validate every user has head = true. but,  remaining users dnt have **head = true**, so error showing link this.

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'head' of undefined**

i try to solve this issue below

***ngIf="(access.access$ | async)?.role.head || null"**.

but except solution like this ***ngIf="(access.access$ | async)?.role.(head || null)"**

beginner at angular help me find out solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is happening due to role is undefined,

what you can do to avoid the issue is to use safe navigation `?` the line would be:

`ngIf="(access.access$ | async)?.role?.head || null"`

This way if role is undefined the code will not crash.